# Any idea why ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso can not be mounted?

Tags: mount, 64-bit, iso, xen

I tried to set up an Ubuntu 14.04.02 amd64 virtual machine on a Citrix Xenserver host but it is not possible to proceed with the installation because the ISO can not be mounted.

I tried diffferent host servers, download mirrors and also ISO files of the different Ubuntu versions.
The curious thing is, that the only ISO which is not working is Ubuntu 14.04.02 amd64 ISO, all other versions e.g. 12.04 amd64, 14.10 amd64 and the ubuntu-14.04.2-server-i386.iso are working without problems.

Related to this fact I am not sure if it is a problem related to the ISO. I can not really believe but I can not see any other cause when it is only this specific amd64 version which can not be mounted.
The installation process first starts as normal but after CD/DVD detecion the error is shown, that the CD/DVD can not be mounted.

Is there any difference to the other ISO files?

Comment: What is the disk stanza you are using to configure xen?

Comment: I use Xenserver based on Xen kernel, there is no real xen configuration file in this case. The VMs are created with Citrix Xencenter

Comment: What kind of device do you have it configured to emulate?  Does it show up as an ide cdrom?  virtio?  scsi?  You might want to see what `blkid` sees when run from the cd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. I had the same issue when booting the installer from a USB - is this what you are doing? If you have used some utility to create it, it may not have worked correctly with the newest image. Just do (please, make sure you put YOUR actual paths) the following from some Linux installation (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will work even from that same session where you've got stuck, just reboot once the `dd` finishes):

```
dd if=ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M && sync
```

and `sdb` in my example is the device name for my USB drive. You need to type it just like this, without any 1,2 etc at the end, just the name of the device "as a whole".